# Send the download link of the uploaded file in a mail

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the "[jquery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)" in my website.
The plugin give me a feature to download the file after uploaded it, and here's the code

```
<td class="download">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" class="btn modal-download" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">
                <i class="icon-download"></i>
                Download</a>
            </td>
```

Now, I need to make user can send email with the downloaded url of the uploaded file, so I used a [fancy contact form](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/fancy-contact-form/demo.php) to send email by each uploaded file, and here's the code

```
<td class="mail">
                <div id="form-container">
    <h1>Fancy Contact Form</h1>
    <h2>Drop us a line and we will get back to you</h2>

    <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="fancymail/submit.php">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
          <td width="15%"><label for="name">Name</label></td>
          <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter]]" name="name" id="name" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['name']?>" /></td>
          <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="email">Email</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['email']?>" /></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="subject">Subject</label></td>
          <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter]]" name="subject" id="subject" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['subject']?>" /></td>
          <!--<td><select name="subject" id="subject">
            <option value="" selected="selected"> - Choose -</option>
            <option value="Question">Question</option>
            <option value="Business proposal">Business proposal</option>
            <option value="Advertisement">Advertising</option>
            <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
          </select>          </td>-->
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"><label for="message">Message</label></td>
          <td><textarea name="message" id="message" class="validate[required]" cols="35" rows="5"><?=$_SESSION['post']['message'] ?></textarea></td>
          <!--efoula-->

          <!--efoula-->
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="captcha"><?=$_SESSION['n1']?> + <?=$_SESSION['n2']?> =</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" name="captcha" id="captcha" /></td>
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
          <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Reset" />

          <?=$str?>          <img id="loading" src="img/ajax-load.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
      <?=$success?>
    </div>
            </td>
```

Also the fancy contact form using a submit.php file to send the mail, and here's the code

```
<?php

/* config start */

$emailAddress = 'email@example.com';

/* config end */
$url = "http://domain.com/files=" .$file_name ;


require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";
require "../server/php/upload.class.php";

session_name("fancyform");
session_start();


foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
    $_POST[$k]=stripslashes($_POST[$k]);

    $_POST[$k]=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$k]));
}


$err = array();

if(!checkLen('name'))
    $err[]='The name field is too short or empty!';

if(!checkLen('email'))
    $err[]='The email field is too short or empty!';
else if(!checkEmail($_POST['email']))
    $err[]='Your email is not valid!';

if(!checkLen('subject'))
    $err[]='You have not selected a subject!';

if(!checkLen('message'))
    $err[]='The message field is too short or empty!';

if((int)$_POST['captcha'] != $_SESSION['expect'])
    $err[]='The captcha code is wrong!';


if(count($err))
{
    if($_POST['ajax'])
    {
        echo '-1';
    }

    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
    {
        $_SESSION['errStr'] = implode('<br />',$err);
        $_SESSION['post']=$_POST;

        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }

    exit;
}


$msg=
'Name:  '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
Download: '.$url.'<br />


Message:<br /><br />

'.nl2br($_POST['message']).'

';


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->Subject = "A new ".mb_strtolower($_POST['subject'])." from ".$_POST['name']." | contact form feedback";

$mail->MsgHTML($msg);

$mail->Send();


unset($_SESSION['post']);

if($_POST['ajax'])
{
    echo '1';
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['sent']=1;

    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    exit;
}

function checkLen($str,$len=2)
{
    return isset($_POST[$str]) && mb_strlen(strip_tags($_POST[$str]),"utf-8") > $len;
}

function checkEmail($str)
{
    return preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/", $str);
}

?>
```

Am trying now to post the download url of the uploaded file in the message of the mail,
I tried to add it in ($msg= Download: '.$url.'), and I set the ($url = "http://domain.com/files=" .$file_name ; ), but when I received the mail I just received (Download: /file= "without the file name").

**I need to post the full url of the uploaded file in the mail.
Any Help???**

Comment: what is `$file_path`? Is it defined anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in submit.php `$url = "http://exemple.com/files=" .$file_name ;`

`$file_name` is **undefined**; you need to post this data from your form as well.

### Answer Part 1:  File.URL is not passed, or showed to the user

Assuming that `<td class="download">` is in the same page of your form in `<td class="mail">`

add the value you want to use in your form with an hidden input

```
 <input type="hidden" name="url" value="{%=file.url%}" />
```

in submit.php change

`Download: '.$url.'<br />`

for

`Download: '.$_POST['url'].'<br />`

your problem is that in your form you don't post the related `{%=file.url%}` data.

### Answer Part 2: $emailAddress = 'email@example.com';

$emailAddress is assigned the string 'email@example.com'
overwrite the value of $emailAddress with $_POST['email']. (in this example i overwrite the value of $url and create a variable $usrname and assign them the $_POST equivalent )

Replace

```
$msg=
'Name:  '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
Download: '.$url.'<br />


Message:<br /><br />

'.nl2br($_POST['message']).'

';
```

With this

```
$usrname = $_POST['name'];
$emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
$url = $_POST['url'];

$msg=
'Name:  '.$usrname.'<br />
Email:  '.$emailAddress.'<br />
Download: '.$url.'<br />


Message:<br /><br />

'.nl2br($_POST['message']).'

';
```

Comment: Ok I have another question if you don't mind, I need to give the users a permission to send this mail from their email addresses, as I need to replace the ($emailAddress = 'email@example.com';) with the user email??? can you help?

Comment: i will refine my answer to answer the 2nd part of your question , please , add this 2nd question in your original question.

Comment: I made it .... Thanks man for your prompt reply, I finally changed the ($emailAddress) with the user address. Thanks again "you made my day".

Answer (score 0):

It is better to check if the variable you use exists, for example:

```
$url = isset($file_name) ? 'http://domain.com/files=' .$file_name : 'http://domain.com/files=no_img';
```

If you get "no_img" in URL, than the variable `$file_name` not exists. Maybe it is defined in another php file that you should include it in that script.

Comment: Thanks for help. I got "no_img" in URL.
So, how to exist the ($file_name) in (submit.php), I have just required (require "../server/php/upload.class.php";), is this enough or I have to do another thing. "Sorry am just beginner in php :D"